# Oracle Developer With Ms access

Tags: oracle, ms-access

Is there any way to attach Oracle form Builder with ms access to make forms and reports from access DB.???

Comment: Please go back through your questions, review the answers you have received so far and **accept** those that you consider best, to acknowledge the time an effort other people have spent helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is - it involves creating connections from windows (DSN) have a look a this guide [here](http://gskaushik.blogspot.com/2009/05/oracle-forms-conection-to-msaccess.html) its a bit dated but principles are the same.

One would have to question what you are doing using an ACCESS backend though - and warn you away from any high volume / high user applications.

Comment: I already visited the article but there is confliction in it that what user name and passoword has to passed for connecting to database from oracle forms?

Comment: How is it conflicting? A simmilar guide is here: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=495283

Comment: Its not working here.I configured all well but when i connect the form then it gives error